# How to manage both OpenGL and Direct3D rendering in the same application

Tags: opengl, direct3d

The target is to make a rendering engine, how could one manage to have both OpenGL and Direct3D and be able to switch from one renderer to the other. This is mostly a design problem. My best guess is some kind of polymorphic behavior.

Comment: That is a rather broad question. A "simple" approach would be to create your own abstract renderer which then has two practical backend implementations. One for OpenGL, one for Direct3D. For some inspiration you could look at http://www.geometrictools.com/ The code available there, as well as some of Eberly's books might provide for some good reading.

Comment: Of course you know both APIs (as otherwise your question won't make any sense), so you know that both rely on pretty much the exact same general concepts and objects. Thus *Bart*'s and *Eberly*'s approach is the IMHO usual one. Make an abstract renderer interface and abstract base classes for things like buffers, textures, shaders, ... and implementations for the respective APIs. Other than that general (and pretty obvious) advice require a more detailed question. But also *datenwolf* is correct in that you shouldn't expect to magically switch betwenn GL and D3D during runtime.

Comment: And of course you may encounter some small (but unfortunately important) differences in some particular implementations of certain features. But those will be more specific questions.

Comment: If it is really the dynamic switch between both platforms you're after (though I guess not), then you may also take a look at nVidia's [NV_DX_interop](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/DX_interop.txt) GL extension, though I don't have any experience with it and have heard it being far from actually useable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how could one manage to have both OpenGL and Direct3D

Put each renderer into a dynamic library and have them export a common set of functions.

> and be able to switch from one renderer to the other.

By loading the right library file. Prepare for major PITA if trying to do this at arbitrary times. It's easiest done at program startup.